# Добавление текста двигает блок вниз

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется примерно такой блок:

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="error-text"><span></span></div>
  <div id="cont-head">...</div>
  <div id="cont-body">...</div>
</div>
```

К блоку `cont` применен `position: fixed`, это что-то вроде карточки, в которой находятся различные кнопки. При нажатии на эти кнопки мне необходимо добавлять в `span` текст ошибок (банально через `.text()` у JQuery), он должен отображаться над карточкой. Но суть в том что при добавлении текста карточка (а точнее её контент) двигается вниз в зависимости от размера текста. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы независимо от размера текста карточка не двигалась, а текст появлялся ровно над ней.

Вот, на всякий случай, визуализация проблемы:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('error-text').firstChild.innerText = 'some error text here';
}
```

```css
#cont {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 250px;
}

#cont-head {
  background: gray;
}

#cont-body {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

#error-text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="error-text"><span></span></div>
  <div id="cont-head">some header</div>
  <div id="cont-body">
    some content
    <button id="btn">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#error-text` присваиваем  `position:absolute; bottom:40px;`

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('error-text').firstChild.innerText = 'some error text here';
}
```

```css
#cont {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 250px;
}

#cont-head {
  background: gray;
}

#cont-body {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

#error-text {
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="error-text"><span></span></div>
  <div id="cont-head">some header</div>
  <div id="cont-body">
    some content
    <button id="btn">click</button>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: В данном случае, если текста будет больше, он залезет на карточку

Comment: @Antoxer А Вы проверяли? Не должен залезать. Кстати, более надежный вариант: `bottom: 100%`, а дополнительный отступ, если нужен, при помощи `margin-bottom`.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey с `bottom` в пикселях проверял. А вот ваш вариант со `100%` - рабочий, до него как то не додумался, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, чего вы хотите.

position: fixed применен к оболочке cont, а текст и все другие элементы находятся внутри. И сдвигается не ваш блок, а содержимое блока увеличивается на высоту текста ошибки.

Единственный выход, который я вижу:

Можно заранее задать место для текста ошибки, сделать отступ сверху, задать оболочку для текста с определенной высотой, равной отступу сверху. Навешать overflow: hidden на обертку для текста ошибки и радоваться.

Получиться примерно так:

```
#error-text {
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
```

Но если текст ошибки будет слишком большим, то он не поместиться весь

Comment: Да, не совсем верно выразился, двигается контент блока, а не блок

Comment: Как вы и написали, если текст будет большим, то он не поместится. Мне нужно решение, не зависящее от размера текста. Пусть он хоть "в потолок" уходит, но карточку двигать нельзя

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос, а куда его поместить? Чтоб он не был поверх другого контента?
Можно обрезать слишком длинный текст и вставлять для него многоточие

Comment: Не страшно, если он будет поверх другого контента. Единственное условие - висеть над карточкой и не двигать её контент